# How to display the special characters with a combination of PHP code snippet in it

Tags: php, html, special-characters, code-snippets

Am trying to display some random combination of special characters. Am already using UTF-8 encode. But sometimes due to the combination of `<?` the remaining characters followed by this combination are not displayed.

For example: For the below HTML code

```
<p>MRTest007865@%$%$%^$%><?Ñ£©¶</p>
```

I expect the output as:

```
MRTest007865@%$%$%^$%><?Ñ£©¶
```

But the actual output is:

```
MRTest007865@%$%$%^$%>
```

Comment: Are you running your code in a browser? If yes, then try "view source" to check the actual source. If the string has some `<` and `>`, it could be that the browser renders them as elements (which might make them invisible on the page, but not in the source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using utf8_encode function

```
echo utf8_encode("MRTest007865@%$%$%^$%><?Ñ£©¶");
```

you can also try to use htmlspecialchars check the documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: The second sentence in the question: _"Am already using UTF-8 encode"_

Comment: have you tried htmlspecialchars function. you can check it on this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.